# Google Map, how to make it look brighter? it looks a little dark

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

Hi I'm using google map in my app and I'm wondering if there's a way to make it look brighter, clearer, right now it looks a little dark specially when you are looking at places with lots of vegetation like London, it is a very dark green and I would like to make it look brighter. I was testing my app outdoors there was a lot of sun and the screen automatically increased the brightness to the max and the map looked beautiful, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on OP's comment on answer posted by Carlos.

Since you said, that's just the way Google maps is, that is just the default Google Maps theme.

You can change the theme to however you want.

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

This site will show you the options and give basic JSON format at the end for you to put in a file and create your own theme. You can make it lighter or darker.

When you get the JSON at the end, understand it. The site only allows few options to change but you can modify JSON and really create a very unique theme.

To learn more and understand the JSON object provided, read more here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/style-reference

Comment: @Ray please accept the answer if this provided you with answer or enough info to get to the answer

Comment: sure just one little question the styling doesn't work when the map is in hybrid or satellite mode right? :/

Comment: @Ray that's correct. Satellite or satellite based (hybrid) types can not be styled

Comment: hello @THEPATEL, i am not understanding what to do, it only show [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/btcHA.png ]. can you please help me with this, my map is in dialog and looks dim, so how can i make it looks like Regular map.

Comment: @RaviVaniya It looks like you didn't change any style or theme so it is giving you a JSON back. Select a different theme and click "FINISH", you will get a full JSON you can use

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is for the theme you are using in your activity.

Try this:

```
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

If you want more information about this, visit [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4902).

Comment: thank you but nothing happened, my map looks similar to the google maps app so I guess that's the way it is